# ruby soft delete_if method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I have an array in ruby, I can run a delete_if block on it.
The problem is that it removes the elements from my array. I'd like the same functionality, except not make changes to the original array, but rather return a new array with the objects removed.

For example:

```
myarr = ["foo", 5, 7, "bar"]
newarr = myarr.delete_if { |e| e.is_a?(String) }
```

would return [5, 7] to `newarr`, but would also make modifications to the original array, `myarr`.

What I'm essentially looking for would be

```
myarr = ["foo", 5, 7, "bar"]
newarr = myarr.soft_delete_if { |e| e.is_a?(String) }
```

so that `newarr` will have the value [5, 7] but `myarr` would still have the same values.

Does something like this exist?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `reject`.

```
> newarr = myarr.reject{ |e| e.is_a?(String) }
=> [5, 7]
> myarr
=> ["foo", 5, 7, "bar"]
```

There is also a related method called `select` which works in the same way as `reject` except it *keeps* the elements for which the predicate returns true instead of rejecting them.

Answer (score 3):

You want [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002196).